# Difference between selenium.selenium and selenium.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I started working recently with selenium with python bindings. `selenium.selenium` module is used in most of the example codes in internet. But, the current [API docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/api.html) of Selenium Python Bindings 2 do not include this module. But the API docs of Selenium RC 1 contain that module.

I can find API docs from Ipython as well with:

```
from selenium import selenium
help(selenium)
```

I have two related questions:

1. Why does the current API docs do not contain selenium.selenium?
2. Should I use selenium.webdriver instead of selenium.selenium in the current version? What is the difference between them?

Comment: There are old selenium (Selenium RC) and new one (the one with WebDriver). I suppose `selenium.selenium` is for backward compatibility (old Selenium) while `selenium.webdriver` is for new version.

Answer (score 0):

The link given is not the official documentation, please refer official API documentation here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html (This has full API inlcuding old RC API)
*selenium.selenium* is the old RC API.  For new projects it is recommended to use the *selenium.webdriver* API.